# Intercepting an email being sent out from Java application

Tags: java, email, smtp

I currently have a web application which sends out an email to localhost:2525, and I've been able to intercept these messages using FakeSMTP Server (http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/). Problem is, I'd like to do so with Java. Is there any way to intercept the email using Java and being able to read the contents of the email in Java?

Comment: The simple answer to your question is no, without additional coding (a lot of coding). If you want to know how you can do it, you should listen from Java on port 2525 and you should implement the SMTP protocol. Anyway, the main question here is, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Theoretically you could use [this Java SMTP server implementation](https://github.com/jcomo/smtpd-java) and either import it in your project as JAR library, or simply fork the code and use it. I have not tested it though.

Comment: @OctavianR. I'm trying to do some testing to check whether the emails being sent is correct(The format, the content according to who the email is being sent out to, etc). Do you have any other idea which might be better for this purpose?

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC Unfortunately searching so far yielded no already-widespread SMTP server implementations in Java. Any idea on any reliable, wide-spread implementation?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I will suggest to use Mockito with spy option. Basically your application is responsible to format the email and the javax mail lib is used only to send the email. In your case I will try to intercept that part of the code that is responsible to format the email and to make assertions over the result.